# What is the SQL Server equivalent of PostgreSQL's NpgsqlException and how to get the error code for when the table is not found in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, postgresql, sqlexception

I am using Entity Framework and I want to support both PostgreSQL and MS SQL Server. I have my code already written for Postgres, and now I'm writing it for SQL Server. It's basically the same, except for when I need to make sql queries (slightly different parameter formatting) and when I need to handle exceptions. For Postgres, when a query is made and the table is not found, then I want to catch that exception and manually create the table. Here is a code snippet of an example try-catch block for Postgres:

```
try
{
    //Add a column to the table. Also don't worry, in my actual code I'm using
    //parameters to avoid SQL injection attacks.
    await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("ALTER TABLE "
    + entityTableName + " ADD " + sqlFieldName + " " + sqlType);
}
catch (NpgsqlException ex)
{
    //If the table doesn't exist then let's make it.
    if (ex.Code == "42P01") //Error code for when the table can't be found.
    {
        CreateEntitySqlTableAsync(exampleEntity).Wait(); //private method I wrote
    }
    throw;
}
```

I need to write the same thing but to work with SQL Server. This is my attempt:

```
try
{
    //Add a column to the table.
    await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("ALTER TABLE "
    + entityTableName + " ADD " + sqlFieldName + " " + sqlType);
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    //If the table doesn't exist then let's make it.
    if (ex.ErrorCode == "42P01") //This gives an error (ErrorCode needs an int)
    {
        CreateEntitySqlTableAsync(exampleEntity).Wait(); //private method I wrote
    }
    throw;
}
```

I'm not sure what error SQL Server gives for when a table isn't created. I'm not even sure any error is given.

Comment: Since you're using Entity Framework, you should really look into the DatabaseInitializer class(es), and possibly Migrations. They will do most of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: I already have, and believe me, for what I'm doing it's best to create the tables myself. I'm generating both the entities and contexts dynamically with Codedom. I tried using `DatabaseInitializer` set to `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` but it was giving me a hard time. My method of creating the tables works pretty well (at least with Postgres).